# How to do math.power in dynamic linq core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dynamic-linq-core

I'm doing a select to calculate present value like this:

```
.Select("new (Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as profit, sum(cashflow)/power(1+0.04, Key.t) as pv");
```

I have an error at runtime:

> "ExceptionMessage": "No applicable aggregate method 'Power(Double,Int32)' exists"

I also tried C# syntax like this

```
.Select("new (Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as profit, sum(cashflow)/Math.Pow(1+0.04, Key.t) as pv");
```

Looks like the syntax might worked? But still an error like this:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Operator '/' incompatible with operand types 'Decimal?' and 'Double'"

My query before this is long so I won't bore you. But as a test I know this works for sure:

```
.Select("new (Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as profit, sum(cashflow)/Key.t as pv");
```

So it's just the way I'm calling power is having problem.

How to do math power in dynamic linq core?

EDIT:
Thanks to @Fildor in the comment I tried

```
.Select("new (Key.t, Sum(cashflow) as profit, Convert.ToDecimal(sum(cashflow)/Math.Pow(1+0.04, Key.t)) as pv");
```

but I got

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Well, the error message actually tells you what is wrong: the division operator is not defined for nullable decimal and double. So you could simply try to cast the result of `Math.Pow` to `decimal`.

Comment: @Fildor thanks, could show me how to do that, I use Convert.ToDecimal and get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Have you tried `(decimal)( Math.Pow(1.04, Key.t))` ?

Comment: @Fildor Just tried.. strangely. The error is "'.' or '(' or string literal expected". I used exactly as you wrote. ```Sum(cashflow)/((decimal)( Math.Pow(1.04, Key.t)))```

Comment: Is there a whitespace between 1 and .04? It shouldn't.

Comment: @Fildor nope I also tried a simpler expression by applying (decimal) directly on Sum(cashflow) without the Math.Pow and division. It gives the same issue. Perhaps one can't convert type in Dynamic Linq expression? I also tried 'Cast' like the sql expession, but didn't work either. :(